# Decimal to Binary on C library

Tags: c, binary

I want to know if there is a function in C library that convert a decimal to binary number and save number by number in a position on an array. 
For example: 2 -> 10 -> array [0] = 0 array[1] = 1.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to print the number in binary?

Comment: `scanf()` et al; `atoi()`, `strtol()` et al...etc...These can all convert a string containing a decimal number into the internal (binary) notation.  If you want to print a number as a binary value, then you have to work a bit harder; there isn't a function that does that in Standard C.

Comment: I want a function that receives a number and gave me the representation in binary on an array of that number.

Comment: There is no such thing as "convert number". Data(numbers) is stored independent of how you want to represent them. The format of output may differ.

Comment: Insufficient information. Decimal in what format? Array of what? Containing elements of 0 or 1, or 0-255, or ? Judging by the difference between the text of the question and the accepted answer you either don't understand your own question or you don't know what a correct answer would look like. Voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here:

```
void dec2bin(int c)
{
   int i = 0;
   for(i = 31; i >= 0; i--){
     if((c & (1 << i)) != 0){
       printf("1");
     }else{
       printf("0");
     } 
   }
}
```

But this only prints the value of an integer in binary format. All data is represented in binary format internally anyway.

Comment: i will go from 0 to 31. so `i << 32` never executes @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, oops. (recoding)

Comment: That'll work...I recoded it as: `int i = 32; while (i-- > 0) { ...as you have it... }` but the differences are cosmetic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, as long as the OP is happy with whatever code he gets to look at his "binary".. :)

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. There is no array. Impossible to see why the OP accepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define what is a decimal number for you. I am guessing it is character representation (e.g. in ASCII) of that number.

<sup>Notice that numbers are just numbers. Binary or decimal numbers do not exist, but a given number may have a binary, and a decimal, representation. Numbers are not made of digits!</sup>

Then you probably want [sscanf(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or [strtol(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html) pr `atoi` to convert a string to an integer (e.g. an `int` or a `long`), and [snprintf(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) to convert an integer to a string.

If you want to convert a number to a binary string (with only `0` or `1` `char`-s in it) you need to code that conversion by yourself. To convert a binary string to some `long` use `strtol`.

Comment: You can use `strtol("011010101110101", (char **)0, 2)` to convert the binary string into a `long` value.  There isn't a standard arbitrary-base output function (`ltostr()`?) that generates a binary string representation of a `long` (or any other integer type) value.

Comment: I may have misled you unintentionally; there is no standard function `ltostr()`, though it would be a semi-logical name for a function that converted a `long` to a string.

Comment: No, I did say that you have to convert a number to a binary string by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in C standard library. Anyway, you can write your own:

```
void get_bin(int *dst, intmax_t x);
```

Where `dst` is the resulting array (with `1`s and `0`s), and `x` is the decimal number.

For example:

C89 version:

```
#include <limits.h>

void get_bin(int *dst, int x)
{
    int i;

    for (i = sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        *dst++ = x >> i & 1;
}
```

C99 version:

```
/* C99 version */
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void get_bin(int *dst, intmax_t x)
{
    for (intmax_t i = sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        *dst++ = x >> i & 1;
}
```

It works as follow: we run through the binary representation of `x`, from left to right. The expression `(sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1)` give the number of bits of `x` - 1. Then, we get the value of each bit (`*dst++ = x >> i & 1`), and push it into the array.

Example of utilisation:

```
void get_bin(int *dst, int x)
{
    int i;

    for (i = sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        *dst++ = x >> i & 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int buf[128];       /* binary number */
    int n = 42;         /* decimal number */
    unsigned int i;

    get_bin(buf, n);

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof n * CHAR_BIT; ++i)
        printf("%d", buf[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, doesn't your test program output the digits backwards?  And shouldn't it output a newline at the end?

Comment: Because, in my whole source code (copy/pasted), it is not used once. I'll edit.

Comment: Some particular reason to use int array instead of char array and `*dst++ = (x >> i & 1) ? '1' : '0';` or something like that?

Comment: I've just followed what the OP was looking for.

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. The input value is already binary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that explicitly uses a string buffer:

```
#include <string.h>

const char *str2bin(int num, char buffer[], const int BUFLEN)
{
    (void) memset(buffer, '\0', BUFLEN );
    int     i  = BUFLEN - 1;        /* Index into buffer, running backwards.    */
    int     r  = 0;                 /* Remainder.                               */
    char    *p = &buffer[i - 1];    /* buffer[i] holds string terminator '\0'.  */

    while (( i >= 0 ) && ( num > 0 ))   {
        r   = num % 2;
        num = num / 2;
        *p  = r + '0';
        i--;
        p--;
    }
    return (p+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to convert a decimal to binary in C. However, I have created a program that converts decimal to binary and stores it in an array before printing it. I hope this helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[8];
    int n, b = 7, c = 0;

    printf("enter a number\n");

    scanf("%d", & n);

    while (b >= 0)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            a[b] = 1;
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if (n == 0)
        {
            a[b] = 0;
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            a[b] = 0;
        }
        else if (n % 2 == 1)
        {
            a[b] = 1;
        }

        n = n / 2;
        b--;
    }

    if (c == 1)
    {
        for (int i = b - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );` 
Find more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) ...

Comment: That would convert binary to decimal. Not what was asked for.

Answer (score -1):

the function should go like this:

```
int dec2bin(int n){
  static int bin,osn=1,c;
  if(n==0) return 0;
  else {
    c=n%2;
    bin += c*osn;
    osn*=10;
    dec2bin(n/2);
  }
  return bin;
}
```

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. The input value is already binary.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know there is no such function in any C library. But here's a recursive function that returns a binary representation of a decimal number as int:

```
int dec2bin(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    return n % 2 + 10 * dec2bin(n / 2);
}
```

The max number that it can represent is 1023 (1111111111 in binary) because of *int* data type limit, but you can substitute *int* for *long long* data type to increase the range. Then, you can store the return value to array like this:

```
int array[100], i = 0;
int n = dec2bin(some_number);

do{
    array[i] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    i++;
}while(n > 10)
```

I know this is an old post, but i hope this will still help somebody!

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. This code does the opposite.

Answer (score -2):

If it helps you can convert any decimal to binary using bitset library, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;

int main(){

  int decimal = 20;

  bitset<5> binary20(decimal);

  cout << binary20 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

So, you have an output like **10100**. Bitsets also have a "**toString()**" method for any purpose.

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. The input value is already binary.