# Different answer in CodeBlocks in windows and Gedit on Linux Decimal to Binary Conversion

Tags: c

This is the code of Converting Decimal to Binary. However when I test on CB with number 5 and 20 it gave me a weird answers ( 100, 10098) but when I tested on Gedit on Linux, everything is fine ( 101, 10100).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter an int:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int result=0, c=0;
    while(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2==1){
             result += pow(10,c);
        }
        c++;
        n=n/2;
    }
    printf("%d\n",result);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger and seeing what is assigned to what as you work through?

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' in this line: `result += pow(10,c);`. But here you program works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099270/2591612

Comment: its just the thing in Window i dont know how to do the debug like in Linux. As I mentioned above, my code works fine in Linux (gave me exactly correct ans), however, in Windows, it behave in total different way. can anb help me. thanks

Comment: and i know there are many way to solve this prob. the other way i knew and seem to works fine with both Win and Linux. just this one

Comment: If you don't have a handy debugger then just add something like `printf("Start of loop: %d %d %d\n", n, c, result);` at the start of the loop (immediately after the `{` following the `while`) and `printf("End of loop: %d %d %d\n", n, c, result);` at the end of the loop (immediately before the matching `}`.

Comment: Thanks Vicky for ur recommendation. I tried it and find out that i have to initialize the variable for c and result as double cuz pow fuction requires double to work with. I think Linux will do the conversion but windows is a bit more trickier. thanks